# Python Expression for Labeling Addresses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

I am trying to create a python label expression where only the **first word** of the address is labeled. Additionally I only want a label to appear if it is a **number** not a word.

I have used this script but it still labels numbers in other parts of the field. I only want the first number.

```
def FindLabel ( [ADDR] ):
  import re
  output = re.sub("[^0-9 ]", "", [ADDR])
  return output
```

I have also tried this script. It labels the first word, but is not specific on character type.

```
def FindLabel ([ADDR]) :
    if [ADDR]  is not None:
        split_field = ([ADDR]).split(" ")[0]
        return str(split_field)
    else:
        return None
```

Is there a way to combine these scripts to achieve the label I'm trying to generate?

Answer (score 3):

You could get fancier with the regex, or take your split approach and test the result before returning it.  Something like:

```
def FindLabel ([ADDR]) :
    if [ADDR] is not None:
        split_field = ([ADDR]).split(" ")[0]
        try:
            return str(int(split_field))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None
```

That will try to convert the word to an integer.  If it works, return it as a string.  If it fails, do nothing and return `None` later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to get fancier with the regular expression you can. When writing regular expressions I'd recommend a tool like https://www.debuggex.com/ to help see what's going on.

Currently your expression is `[^0-9 ]` which matches anything that's not a number or a space, and replaces it with an empty string. So for example:

- `"42 Wallaby Way, Sydney"` gives you `"42   "`
- `"Apt 56B, Whitehaven Mansions, Sandhurst Sq, London"` gives you `" 56     "`

Regular expressions are pretty powerful (see https://www.regular-expressions.info/ for tutorials and cheat sheets). In your instance, a regular expression matching the first word of a string, if and only if it is a number, looks like:

`^(\d+)`

To break it down:

- The `^` at the start (outside brackets) means the start of the string
- `\d` is any digit - it's the same as `[0-9]`
- `+` is one or more matches
- The brackets `()` put what's inside them into a group, so you can get that value back

So, to put it in your Python function:

```python
import re

def find_label(address):
    match = re.match(r'^(\d+) ', address)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)  # the group of digits
```

And trialling this with the some addresses:

```python
> find_label('42 Wallaby Way, Sydney')
'42'
> find_label('Apt 56B, Whitehaven Mansions, Sandhurst Sq, London')
None
> find_label('221B Baker Street')  # Note the B is part of the first word
None
> find_label('742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield')
'742'
```